# Data Manipulation In Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Fairly easy one I hope.

If I have a column of values in a sheet, How can I set those values to equal a variable I can work with in VBA.

For instance column A has 100 weight values and column b has 100 height values. In a VBA script I want to set "weight" as all values in column A and height as b. and say BMI = weight * height and then write BMI to column C.

I know I can do this example with formulas but for the actual task I'll be looping this a few hundred times and will not know the column index value.

Thanks!

Edit: To specify further, the columns are randomly arranged. I won't be able to use relative cell references. Ultimately I'll be finding the column, naming it working with the data in reference to another column and then finding the next column and doing the same.

Edit 2: I think answers are focusing on achieving the result I specified in the example rather than implementing the process I was trying to describe.

Comment: Please, please have a relevant title. `For i = FirstRow To LastRow Cells(i,3)=Cells(i,1)*Cells(i,2) Next i`.

Comment: apologies, how would you have titled this?

Comment: Something like `Declaring variables as cell values`, maybe add `looping through rows`.

Answer (score 0):

First determine the limits and then *Select* that part of column **C** you wish to fill and then:

```
Sub BMII()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In Selection
      r.Value = r.Offset(0, -2).Value * r.Offset(0, -1).Value
   Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

Once you have determined which columns and which rows to process, update the parameter section of the following macro and run it:

```
Sub BMIII()

   Dim wcol As String, hcol As String, bcol As String
   Dim start_row As Long, end_row As Long, i As Long

   ''''''''''' PARAMETER SECTION ''''''
   start_row = 5
   end_row = 200
   wcol = "A"
   hcol = "B"
   bcol = "C"
   ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   For i = start_row To end_row
      Cells(i, bcol).Value = Cells(i, wcol).Value * Cells(i, hcol).Value
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: ?? O_o ?? Why use a `Selection` ??

Comment: Does work but selecting each range I want to work with is a little cumbersome.

Comment: Also edited my question to explain why offsets aren't usable in my case.

Comment: @user3033634  How would you like to tell the macro which **3** columns to use??

Comment: I have a dictionary of each column heading matched to the name of the column heading I want to compare it too and i my plan is to find each (prob with a loop) calc and write the difference between them to a new cell in a diff sheet and move to the next value in the dict.

Comment: i need to operate on the whole column at once and then write it all together elsewhere, which is why I'm hoping to be able to work with strings of data instead of cells individually.

Comment: @user3033634 I understand...................without details on how to select the three columns, I can't update the code.

Comment: what I'm really getting at is: if you have two columns of cells, 4;5;2;7 and 6;3;8;1 how can I make a script that identifies the first column values as A the second as B and say Z=A*B and then be able to write Z into a third column.

Comment: @user3033634  If you had a novice employee, and gave that employee the task of entering formulas into a column based on two other columns, you would tell that employee which **3** columns to use................tell me the same thing!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for you to see how this simple task can be done :

```
Sub user3033634()
Dim LastRow As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        .Cells(i, "C") = .Cells(i, "A") * .Cells(i, "B")
        '.Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(i, 1) * .Cells(i, 2)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```